# What are the properties of median-unbiased estimators?

Tags: parameter-estimation, median

On Wikipedia it says that " A median-unbiased estimator minimizes the risk with respect to the absolute-deviation loss function, as observed by Laplace." How to prove this?

Note that I asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64841/does-a-median-unbiased-estimator-minimize-mean-absolute-deviance) why simulation results does not support the above statement.